# Load file csv from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to upload a CSV file to the distributed file system hdfs with:

```
hadoop fs -put
```

[image: jps]

```
But I get the following error:
put: ´.´: No such file or directory: ´hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser´
```

[image: load csv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Destination HDFS directory first. It looks like /user/hduser directory is not present in HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hduser
```

Then copy the file to HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -put LOCAL_FILE_PATH DESTINATION_HDFS_PATH
```

Example:    `hdfs dfs -put ./ /tmp`

Note: Replace LOCAL_FILE_PATH with your local file and DESTINATION_HDFS_PATH with the destination HDFS Path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to upload the file without specifying an explicit location.  If you don't specify a destination, it will upload it to the current user's hdfs home directory, which doesn't exist for the current user.

try specifying an hdfs folder location.

```
hadoop fs -put <local file> <hdfs directory>
```